# Convert UTC date into a DD-MM-YYYY format-EXTJS

Tags: extjs

How to convert `Thu May 03 2018 14:34:57 GMT-0700 (PDT)` into 
`"03-MAY-2018"` format in ExtJs.

I tried using the Ext.Date, but gives me undefined as I'm using older ExtJs version that does not have Date prop.

Comment: Is the value a date object or a string?

Comment: the value is a string

Comment: What is your ExtJS version?

Comment: I'm using the extjs 3 verison

Comment: What is known as `Ext.Date` in ExtJS >=4, is known as `Date` in ExtJS 3.4. [`Date`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Date). Is your date a string or is it a javascript date?

Comment: the value is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to ExtJS, but you can just do:

```
let date = 'Thu May 03 2018 14:34:57 GMT-0700 (PDT)';
let dp = date.split(' ');
let newDate = dp[2] + '-' + dp[1].toUpperCase() + '-' + dp[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date();
date.toLocaleDateString("en-au", {year: "numeric", month: "short",day: "numeric"}).replace(/\s/g,'-')
```

I hope this is what you want.
Refer: [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)